# Изменение названия текста при клике на ссылку

Tags: javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста, как при помощи скрипта сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на ссылку напр. '+ все', после открытия скрытого блока, ссылка меняла свой текст на '- все'.

Что есть:

```
function showHide(element_id) {
           //Если элемент с id-шником element_id существует
           if (document.getElementById(element_id)) { 
               //Записываем ссылку на элемент в переменную obj
               var obj = document.getElementById(element_id);

               //Если css-свойство display не block, то: 
               if (obj.style.display != "block") { 
                   obj.style.display = "block"; //Показываем элемент
               }
               else  { obj.style.display = "none"; //Скрываем элемент
                     } //document.getElementById("link").innerHTML=ref;
           }
           //Если элемент с id-шником element_id не найден, то выводим сообщение
           else alert("Элемент с id: " + element_id + " не найден!"); 
       }
```

Мне необходимо сделать на javascript без помощи библиотек jquery.

Сделал на jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/zVhDD/1/

Comment: сделайте jsfiddle с релевантной разметкой

Comment: сделал на jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/zVhDD/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

по поводу вашего примера:

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/zVhDD/6/ (минимальные изменения);

я просто передаю this в функцию

ну и в рамках программы "я сделаю это без js":

[[@dzhioev](/users/552/dzhioev)](/users/552/dzhioev) - я изменил ваш пример, сделал без js, вернул надпись вниз листа: http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/zVhDD/7/

Answer (score 2):

Менять стили из JS не очень хорошо. Если написать нормальный CSS, то кода на JS почти не остается.

http://jsfiddle.net/zVhDD/5/

Comment: Круто, спасибо за пример!

Answer (score 0):

Может быть этот [пример](http://alt-f4.ru/expanding-menu-by-jquery?page=1#0) вам поможет

Comment: мне необходимо сделать на javascript без помощи библиотек jquery.